# Big union and big intersection

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Define $A_k = [k − 1, 2k + 3]$. 
>   Write the following sets: $\displaystyle\bigcap_{k=3}^7 A_k$, and $\displaystyle\bigcup_{k=0}^{10} A_k$.

I'm really confused by big unions and intersections can anyone show me how to answer this question.

Comment: I've edited the question body. Please let me know if this is what was intended

Comment: WaveX, yes this is what was intended thank you.

Comment: "write the following sets" is not really a question; they are already written. Is the question to write the sets in some different form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Big unions and big intersections are unions (or intersections) over an indexing set for example your big intersection you are looking at:

$\bigcap\limits_{k=3}^7 [k-1,2k+3]=[2,9]\cap[3,11]\cap[4,13]\cap[5,15]\cap[6,17]=[6,9]$.

This should (hopefully) be enough to help you do the union yourself.